# Possible to optimize this Dust "logic"?

Tags: templates, optimization, dust.js

I'm working in a Dust partial and want to display a fixed header if a condition is met.

First, I want to know if the user said they're working in a given city. If they aren't in any cities in my list, I want to display nothing...UNLESS they live in Hawaii. Then I want to show that same header.

```
{@select key=workingCity}
  {@eq value=1}Fixed Header{/eq} {! Pittsburgh !}
  {@eq value=2}Fixed Header{/eq} {! Paris !}
  {@eq value=3}Fixed Header{/eq} {! Phoenix !}
  {@default}
    {@eq key=state value=50} {! Hawaii !}
      Fixed Header
    {/eq}
  {/default}
{/select}
```

**Is there any way I can avoid placing 'Fixed Header' in four different locations?**

I know I could just reference another partial with that specific title inside it...but then I need to put that partial reference in four locations anyway!

Is this as optimized as it gets?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using a new enough version of dust and dust-helpers, you can use the new `{@any}` and `{@none}` helpers-- they're for exactly this use case.

```
{@select key=workingCity}
  {@eq value=1/} {! Pittsburgh !}
  {@eq value=2/} {! Paris !}
  {@eq value=3/} {! Phoenix !}
  {@any}Fixed Header{/any}
  {@none}
    {@eq key=state value=50} {! Hawaii !}
      Fixed Header
    {/eq}
  {/none}
{/select}
```

That brings you down to two instances of the header, which may be good enough. Documentation for these helpers is at [Dust Helpers](http://www.dustjs.com/guides/dust-helpers).

You can also bring even more logic out of your template into a **context helper**, which is something Dust is really good at. That way, the logic remains in Javascript, and the template is just for display.

```
{#showFixedHeader}
  Fixed Header
{:else}
  Optionally something else!
{/showFixedHeader}
```

And in your context:

```
{
  "showFixedHeader": function(chunk, context) {
    var workingCity = context.get('workingCity');
    var state = context.get('state');
    return [1,2,3].indexOf(workingCity) > -1 || state === 50;
  }
}
```

Now your template is super readable, and if you add a fourth city the template doesn't have to change at all.

Comment: Much appreciated! Had to go with the amazing {any} and {none} tags because I have no access to my template's context in my environment. That said, I'm quite pleased with the result! Thank you so much!